# Spring data Query-By-Example

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to filter away results returned by my `AppService` by the current `login` of the user who is not part of the `allowedusers` set of `App` entity.

The current approach I am taking is Query-By-Example. The filtering of `platform` field works perfectly but the filter by `allowedusers` doesn't seems to be in effect?

**App Entity**

```
@ManyToMany
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@JoinTable(name = "app_alloweduser",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="apps_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="allowedusers_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
private Set<User> allowedusers = new HashSet<>();

public void setAllowedusers(Set<User> users) {
        this.allowedusers = users;
    }
```

**AppService**

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Page<AppDTO> findAll(RequestParams requestParams, Pageable pageable) {
    App newApp = new App();
    Example<App> appExample;

    // set to current logged in user
    User user = new User();
    user.setLogin(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin());
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
    users.add(user);
    newApp.setAllowedusers(users);

    // set platform selected
    if (requestParams.platform != null) {
        newApp.setPlatform(requestParams.platform);
    }

    appExample = Example.of(newApp);

    // find by example
    Page<App> results = appRepository.findAll(appExample, pageable);
    return results.map(app -> appMapper.toDto(app));
}
```

Comment: so the query result contains too many `App`-elements which have `allowedUsers` without the user you set or with additional users, correct?

Comment: It basically returns all the `App` without considering the `allowedUsers` field.   In another words, it does not filter away `Apps` where `User` NOT IN `allowedUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Collection-valued properties are not supported for Query By Example in Spring Data JPA

### Long version

[The documentation describes the following limitations of Query By Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.usage) emphasis mine:

> Only supports starts/contains/ends/regex matching for strings and **exact matching for other property types**

So expecting `IN` logic to apply is certainly out of scope of the current implementation.

Further down in the same document it then says:

> Only `SingularAttribute` properties can currently be used for property matching.

Which is a somewhat confusing way to state: **Does work only with simple properties**

Comment: I guess I will have to resort to `@Query` notation as I also do want to enable optional parameters.